# What is the rate of FastForward on iPhone/iPod

Tags: ios, ipod

Can anybody tell what is fast forward rate of iphone’s music player for different duration songs?

For example, if I keep on pressing the FastForward button from the beginning of a track, the time tick goes like 1sec-> 2sec->4sec->6sec-> 9sec and so on…

Is there any known algorithm or formula they use for this?